# Breeze for Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to install Breeze (via composer) into a new Laravel v7 project?

Whenever I try `composer require laravel/breeze --dev`

I get failure with message:

Cannot use laravel/breeze's latest version v1.17.0 as it requires php ^8.0.2 which is not satisfied by your platform.
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/breeze
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

I don't want to use v9 of laravel or php8 due to work on older code.
I created v7 laravel project via composer: `composer create-project laravel/laravel:7.* example_app_name`
Is there a similar command for previous versions of Breeze? And if so, which version would apply?

Comment: You'll need to find the Breeze branch/version that is compatible with Laravel 7 (and PHP 8), then try `composer require laravel/breeze:"<version>" --dev`

Comment: Looking around in packagist, breeze was never compatible with laravel 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it should not be possible. Even [version 0.0.1](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/breeze#v0.0.1) requires Laravel 8.

If you upgrade to Laravel 8 (8.42 minimum version), you should be able to install breeze up to [version 1.10](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/breeze#v1.10.0)